# Calling a specific 'div' element using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wish to extract the second  link (that is the link for the number '2') from the following HTML code:

```
<div class="post-footers">
    1 |<a href="index.html?page=2"> 2 </a>
    |<a href="index.html?page=3"> 3 </a>
    |<a href="index.html?page=4"> 4 </a> 
</div>
```

So I thought to output all the `href` into a list and then extract the element at index 1 like shown below:

```
tags = soup.find("div", class_="post-footer")
links = tags.get('href')
print links[1]
```

But it returns the error:

```
newtags.get('href', None) 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

This means that the tags turned out to be empty. So where in the code did I go wrong?

Thanks, if anyone would be able to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

**Attempt 1**

```
In [1]: tags = soup.find("div", class_ = "post-footers")
In [2]: links = [i.attrs['href'] for i in tags.findAll('a')] 
In [3]: print links
```

**Result 1**

```
['index.html?page=2', 'index.html?page=3', 'index.html?page=4']
```

There was a spelling mistake in your code. You used `post-footer` instead of `post-footers`.

**Attempt 2**

If you use `href` as `True` you will get all the `a` like this,

```
In [28]: tags = soup.find("div", class_ = "post-footers")
In [31]: links = tags.find_all('a',href=True)
```

**Result 2**

```
[<a href="index.html?page=2"> 2 </a>,
 <a href="index.html?page=3"> 3 </a>,
 <a href="index.html?page=4"> 4 </a>]
```

Comment: Ohh that seems nice. I am a little new to python. So, don't mind me asking - it is a regular expression, right? the part "i.attrs..." I did not understand that.

Comment: Also one more question: In the attempt 1, i loops through all the a tags inside the 'div' element. And 'i.attrs' extracts the href part of the 'a' tags and output them as another list? Thanks, by the way.

Comment: @RahulRamesh I have used `list comprehension` there, Found the all `a` and pick the `href` part.

Comment: @RahulRamesh It's not regular expersiion. `attrs` will generate a dict of attributes like this, `{'href': 'index.html?page=2'}`, so you can access the attributes of each.

Comment: one question,  I understood list comprehension. I read more about it from python docs. But, that attrs is not a function, right? Because it seems to be taking href inside square brackets.

Comment: `attrs` is a method, It holds a dictionary.

Comment: Nope, the "tags = soup.find("div", class_ = "post-footers")" is returning "'NoneType' object is not callable". I tried it in a different program, with a different website and all. That part is returning a Null object

Comment: Make sure it's have a `div` element with class name `post-footers`.

Comment: Nope, it is not working. tried in another website also, with the corresponding tags and classes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

You can use RegEx with BeautifulSoup

```
import re
page2Link = soup.find_all(href = re.compile("(page=2)"))

print page2Link
```

Comment: @piyush-s-wanare  re.compile finds tags with matching text right? If that's the case why was parenthesis provides between "page=2"?

Comment: Parentheses mentions that it contains regex.